# sqljdbc_auth.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, dll, jdbc

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 from JAVA code using JDBC sql server with IntegratedSecurity to use Windows Authentication.

SQL authentication worked fine with the code but when I use IntegratedSecurity for Windows Authentication, I am facing sql driver issues. I have provided the brief scenario below.

> **Java Code**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

  public class Sqlselection 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     System.out.println("This programe runs on "+ System.getProperty("java.version"));

               String url="jdbc:sqlserver://*****\\*****;integratedSecurity=true";
               //Masked Server name & DB name
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                Statement s1 = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery("SELECT count(1) myrecords FROM dbo.mytable");
                String[] result = new String[20];
                if(rs!=null){
                    while (rs.next()){
                        for(int i = 0; i <result.length ;i++)
                        {
                            for(int j = 0; j <result.length;j++)
                            {
                                result[j]=rs.getString(i);
                            System.out.println(result[j]);
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


}
```

> **Error while running the code**

**WARNING:** Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : E:\POC\OMSChecker\sqljdbc_auth.dll: **Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform**
**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:** This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:27af9d19-d144-47be-b9cf-bf646ed9bb3f

> **Issue root cause**

sqljdbc_auth.dll is not compatible with current platform.

> **System properties**

C:\Users>java -version

java version "1.6.0_25"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

> **Eclipse properties**

**launcher:** win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807

**Used dll:** E:\sqljdbc_2.0.1803.100_enu.exe\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\auth\x64\sqljdbc_auth.dll

**Added External Jar:** sqljdbc4.jar

**Native library location:** "E:\sqljdbc_2.0.1803.100_enu.exe\sqljdbc_2.0\enu\auth\x64\"

> **Notes**

Can someone kindly help me with the fix. I am new to JAVA coding and I have tried all the solutions given for similar kind of posts.

Comment: You have a 64-bit DLL that you're attempting to use in a 32-bit environment. That won't work, get a 32-bit DLL.

Comment: When I use 32-bit DLL, I am getting the error Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform. \n 

I have three types of DLL in the versions x64/, x86/, IA 64/ for which I get the DLL version mismatch error

Comment: I wish to re-iterate the scenario. Its obvious for someone to say use the other version of DLL.  **x64/, x86/, IA 64/** are the available files. For all the 3 files I am getting error. I don't claim reputation here, I am a DBA looking for options to change data flow by using JAVA rather than using ETL for my requirement, maintain your tone in forums Mr. Kayaman.

Comment: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform, 
Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform these above errors come between x64/, x86/, IA 64/ files deployment. This is  not usual error, so changed IDE between 32 bit eclipse, 64 bit eclipse and tried with IntelliJ too. Re-installed JRE. Nothing helped!!

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Finally found the solution myself by re-installing Windows OS.

Used the same code above with sqljdbc4.jar & below VM argument

-Djava.library.path=E:\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86\

I was able to connect successfully.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a solution that doesn't imply reinstalling OS?